# unable to Find Entry point Fortran Dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, fortran, entry-point

Continuing the last unsolved question about dll, i tried to create fortran dll using g95 with following commands:

`g95 -c FCall.f90`

`g95 -shared -mrtd -o FCall.dll FCall.o`

When I linked it to VB, It shows "Unable to find an entry point named 'FortranCall' in DLL 'C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication5\WindowsApplication5\FCall.dll'."

Here's the FORTRAN code:

```
  SUBROUTINE FortranCall (r1, num)

 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: FortranCall

 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'FortranCall' :: FortranCall

   REAL,INTENT(IN) :: r1          
   REAL,INTENT(OUT) :: num

   num = MOD (r1, 256.0)

 END SUBROUTINE
```

Here's the VB code:

```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()

   r1 = 456.78

   Call FortranCall(r1, Num)

   Text1.Text = Str$(Num)

   End Sub
```

Module code in VB:

`Declare Sub FortranCall Lib"C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication5\WindowsApplication5\FCall.dll"
(r1 As Single, Num As Single)`

Is G95 has own export statement to export function from dll ?
in this subroutine, the export attribute (!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: FortranCall) was used in visual fortran

Comment: Please try to find out how to use the formatting in the edit box. We will help you with the rest, but at least try something.

Comment: Ok, or just find out there is always someone so desperately wanting the +2 from the edit (@Blubberguy22) that he will always do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I still not understand how to use formatting in edit box. But i will find out and use that for next question
Thanks Sergio for editing

Answer (score 5):

The directives you use is a highly compiler specific thing. Even the name suggest it is specific to the DEC compiler (and descendants - Compaq and Intel).

Gfortran has the same thing, but with `!$GCC`, but not G95.

I highly recommend you to use the Fortran 2003 feature `bind(C,name="name")` instead to set the symbol name. See also the tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding.

```
 SUBROUTINE FortranCall (r1, num) bind(C,name="FortranCall")

 !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: FortranCall

 END SUBROUTINE
```

Both GCC and G95 export the symbols by default then, no need for the `dllexport` directive, but leave it there for the Intel Fortran.

Alternatively, you can try the option `-fno-underscoring`, but that is again specific to g95 and will not work with other compilers.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have created dll using above directive. I also tried to create dll using intel visual fortran & visual studio 2008. But when VB call the function, Both methods show the following error message :
**"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"**.

I have no idea to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: This is way too few information to diagnose anything. I don't know VB but try adding `ByRef` to the sub prototype.

Comment: Thank you. This works in VB 2008, but in vb 2010, it still have a problem

Comment: Probably start a new question I think the original problem is solved . I cannot help you more. And include some meaningful descripton, "there is a problem" tells nothing.

Comment: Ok. For now, I think it is enough for my project work with VB 2008 I thought the error in VB 2010 will create a broader problem. So, I have to ask in a new quetion.